# PFFile? is not convertible to 'StringLiteralConvertible' 'AnyObject' is not convertible to 'String'

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, xcode6, pfobject

I just updated:

> xcodeVersion 6.3 (6D570)

Swift 1.2 has messed up my word last night and apparently they have made some changes in either Swift or Parse.

I am confused I just don't know how to fix this issue... Need help please. If someone else has experienced the same and has fixed it, please help me.

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    // MARK: Variables declaration
    @IBOutlet weak var uploadPhotoBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var profilePhotoImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var welcomeMessageLabel: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var greetings: UILabel!

    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    var existingImage : UIImage?
    var user = PFUser.currentUser()




    // The view has loaded this is the function that will be run at first before anything else
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // MARK: make a circle image
        profilePhotoImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profilePhotoImageView.frame.size.width/2
        profilePhotoImageView.clipsToBounds = true

        //show my status 
        var mood = self.user["status"] as! String //=> 'AnyObject' is not convertible to 'String'

        self.greetings.text? = ( "\(mood)" )

        //get image if existing
        self.user[ "avatar" ] as? PFFile //=> 'PFFile? is not convertible to 'StringLiteralConvertible'

        if let userImageFile = self.user["avatar"] as? PFFile {PFFile? is not convertible to 'StringLiteralConvertible'

            userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData:NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

                if error == nil {

                    self.existingImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
                    self.profilePhotoImageView.image = self.existingImage
                }else {

                    let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Oops!", message: "Unable to get your profile photo", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok!")
                    alert.show()

                }
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PFUser.CurrentUser returns optional value, if you sure, that your user is login and have created a PFSession then try this:

**var user = PFUser.currentUser()!**

let me know, if this doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

By trial and error .. this worked for me Parse 1.7.1 and Swift 1.2

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell?

object?["bax"] as? String
object?["abc"] as! PFFile? -> But my image is not showing now ... still trying to solve it.